# Using environment variables

Tags: sapper

I have a sapper project which contains various database secrets and such... So for local development I want to load a `.env` which contains the secrets. I am aware of dotenv. How do I use dotenv to load the `.env` file **only** on my local machine and not on my deployment in cloud run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the dotenv package you can use the [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli). You install it globally and modify the dev npm command and prefix it with `dotenv`. The cli will locate the `.env` file and then run the `sapper dev` command with the environment variables set.

Add another command for production without the dotenv prefix so it uses the environment variables on the machine.

Comment: Could you please share an example?

Comment: @Chris Install dotenv-cli globally with `npm install -g dotenv-cli`. Then run the sapper project with `dotenv npm start` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file.

This way, it won't get deployed to the cloud when you do a git push.

Then go into your cloud provider and set your production environmental variables.